# Where can I ask an open discussion question?

Tags: discussion

I would like to ask a question about Java that doesn't have a specific answer. It's a question to see what people think and to share their opinion.

Will Stack Overflow tolerate this, or is there another Stack Exchange resource where I may ask a question like this?

Comment: `It's a question to see what people think and to share opinion.` I don't think there is any site that allows such type of question.

Comment: That type of question is going to be off-topic throughout the entire Stack Exchange network. See also: http://stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask

Comment: one of the chat rooms might yield positive results, however.

Comment: See also: [Where can I ask questions that don't fit or are off-topic for Stack Overflow?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/8401)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

More than likely that question will not be on-topic for Stack Overflow. Questions are meant to be objective and definitively answerable. Quoting [stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask):

> You should only ask practical, answerable questions based on actual problems that you face. Chatty, open-ended questions diminish the usefulness of our site and push other questions off the front page.

It might behoove you to read the rest of the content on that link.

Comment: hm "behoof; Benefit or advantage", you learn something new every day

Answer (score 3):

The only appropriate place for such a question would be chat.  Other than that, you'll need to go to some other site outside of the SE network.

Answer (score 1):

The appropriate place for discussions is Quora.  They are more about feelings and soft topics anyway.

Barring that, I bet experts-exchange.com would take the question.  :)

Comment: Pretty much any non-SE site out there isn't going to toss out these types of questions.  At least, I've never found any that have such a restriction.