# Where to ask a question about programming, sound and physics?

Tags: discussion, site-recommendation

Sometimes my questions are not well received because they are not asked on the correct site.

I have a question about programming, but it is a theoretical question, not 
 a practical question with a code example as would be appropriate for Stack Overflow. I would like to ask about how sound waves and audio work so that I can develop a way to transform an image of a sound wave back in to sound.

So where can I ask a theoretical question that involves physics and programming?

Edit: To clarify, i didn't wan't an open discussion so it's not a duplicate. But my question was out of topic on this site that why i didn't ask it there. 
Here is the link of the signal post of my question if you want more detail:
[How to transform SoundWave Picture to sound?](https://dsp.stackexchange.com/questions/44734/how-to-transform-soundwave-picture-to-sound)

I don't know if it will be well received or is at a good place. Feel free to tell me now that i have wrote it 
If you thinks it's suit better somewhere else.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Where can I ask an open discussion question?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/195954/where-can-i-ask-an-open-discussion-question)

Comment: @gnat: While the OP's description of the question they want to ask could be clearer, I see no indication that they want to have an "open discussion". It looks to me like they just have a theoretical question about audio processing (or some related topic) that doesn't involve writing or debugging a piece of code. Such questions can certainly be objectively answerable, and indeed make up the majority of on-topic questions on most SE sites other than SO. You wouldn't expect a question on, say, [cooking.se] or [english.se] to have code in it, would you?

Comment: @IlmariKaronen that's what I read - "ask about how ${something work} so that I can develop a way to ${program something}" - and OP seems to want this all in _one_ question. To me this reads even more open ended than [Where to start?](https://softwareengineering.meta.stackexchange.com/a/6367/31260)

Comment: @gnat: If their question was literally "how [do] sound waves and audio work?", then yes, that would indeed be too broad for just about any SE site. But I'm assuming that's not their question, just *what their question is about*, because that makes sense. After all, they really shouldn't be asking their actual question here on meta (not even wrapped in a "where should I ask this?"), since it wouldn't be on-topic here. A description of the topic of their question, as they seem to have provided, should be quite sufficient.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If your question is about audio processing, and you feel it's too theoretical for Stack Overflow, you *might* want to try asking it on [**Signal Processing**](https://dsp.stackexchange.com) Stack Exchange.  You can read [their definition of what's on-topic at the site](https://dsp.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic), and maybe look at some of [their top voted [audio] questions](https://dsp.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/audio?sort=votes) to see if your question looks like it would fit in.

A couple of other Stack Exchange sites that *might* also be suitable, based on things you mentioned in your question, include:

- [Sound Design](https://sound.stackexchange.com) (["about professional sound design and production"](https://sound.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic))
- [Computational Science](https://scicomp.stackexchange.com) (["about computational methods used in technical disciplines"](https://scicomp.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic))
- [Computer Science](https://cs.stackexchange.com) (["covers theoretical and applied computer science at any level"](https://cs.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic))

and, of course:

- [Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com) (["practical, answerable problem[s] unique to software development"](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic))

All that said, I suspect a big part of the reason why your questions may have been poorly received is because your writing is quite hard to make sense of.  Even with rene's spelling and grammar edits to your question above, some parts of it are still hard to understand, and I'm not even 100% sure I've correctly understood what you really want to ask about.

I'm guessing that English isn't your first language.  If so, you might want to look for a suitable forum in your own native language and ask your question there.  Unfortunately, there aren't too many of those on the Stack Exchange network yet (although we do nowadays have localized versions of Stack Overflow in [Portuguese](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/), [Spanish](https://es.stackoverflow.com/), [Russian](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/) and [Japanese](https://jp.stackoverflow.com/)), but there are still quite a few decent forums and Q&A sites in various languages even outside the SE network.

If you can't find a suitable site to ask your question in your own language, my best suggestion (besides practicing your English e.g. by reading lots of well written books, which works but will take a lot of time and effort) would be to ask your question as clearly as possible.  Use short and simple sentences.  Use lots of examples.  Say the most important things several times, in different ways, so that people are more likely to understand you.  Don't use words if you're not sure what they mean.  And use a dictionary to make sure that the words you use really mean what you think they mean.

For example, "programmation" is not an English word.  In this case, it's easy enough to guess that you probably meant "programming", but it's also a mistake that you could've easily caught yourself using an English dictionary and/or a spell checker.  On the other hand, your "sound wave picture" is a grammatically correct phrase consisting of perfectly valid English words, but I'm not sure what you really mean by it.  If I Google for it, [this](https://soundwaveart.com/) is the first result I get.  And if that's what you mean, I'm not sure why you'd want to turn a picture like that back into sound, or even if it's possible (although, apparently, [sometimes it is](https://griffonagedotcom.wordpress.com/2014/11/27/how-to-play-back-a-picture-of-a-sound-wave/)).

Comment: Yes english is not my native language.

sound wave picture is exactly what you find on google.

And my purpose is exactly to transform this kind of image to sound.

Why? I am planning to make a tatoo of sound wave. 
Like someone that matter to me, that say something to me.

But... I would like to have a mobile application that use camera on tatoo and recreate sound. 
(it's possible but a bit hard because of compression and lot of sound thing)  i think in first time Signal processing is a good place